# Sanitising drop down options with a whitelist

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, sanitization, whitelist

I have had a look at this link: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet
which discuss the use of whitelists on drop down menus.

What I dont get is why would you use a whitelist on a list of options when that is all there is to choose from?

I understand why you would use it on user input like typing in your name etc but I dont get why you would use it on options as the user is not physically typing something in.

Or have I just read this wrong?

Comment: You can never trust any input that comes into the application from outside (user, database etc.). If you want to write an application with security in mind, you will need to always validate the input that comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that they will use your form to post to the form processor, but that is not necessarily the case.

Apart from that it is easy to modify the values from the dropdown using for example firebug and post the form after that.

Answer (score 3):

A user can still modify the data in a dropbox and submit data to your page. That's why.